# Perform a calculation n times and sum the results (without VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a way to sum the result of a calculation performed a given, arbitrarily large, number of times.

Suppose I have 15,000 customers each of whom will spend between $100 and $200, and I want to calculate the total revenue.

So I want to calculate Int(Randbetween(100,200)) 15,000 times and sum the results.

For various reasons I don't want to do this by:
- repeating the formula in 15,000 cells
- using a circular reference and Excel's built-in iteration
- using VBA code
- using a Monte Carlo add-in

I have a hunch there's a simple and elegant solution but it has been eluding me.

Comment: You may lean towards Powershell. What operating system will be used to perform the calculation?

Comment: Thanks but if I was going to do scripting in say Powershell I might as well use VBA.  I'm hoping for a solution that just uses standard Excel kit.

Comment: No, this isn't possible without VBA in excel. [see for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939537/how-to-loop-in-excel-without-vba-or-macros)

Comment: Depending on your formula you might be able to rework it as a 'single cell array formula', see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx for details.

Comment: Just to be clear: the values will be integers only from 100-200 inclusive?

Comment: AVee - following your suggestion I explored this option but couldn't find a way to use an array formula to solve this problem without creating an array of 15,000 cells.

Comment: XOR LX - 100-200 (and 15,000) are just example parameters.  I'd like to be able to use the solution for any parameters.

Comment: Raystafarian - I'm suspecting you're right...

Comment: Hi all, you might find my solution interesting - posted below

Answer (score 1):

In order for this calculation to work in one cell, the randomly populated array would have to be populated with a different number in each row.  From what I can tell, Excel doesn't work that way.  The RANDBETWEEN() formula uses the same number in every row of the array.

For example:

I entered the below formula in a cell in a blank worksheet.

**=RANDBETWEEN(100,200)&A1:A10**

I highlighted the entire formula and pressed F9 to calculate in the formula bar.
Excel returned:

**{"180";"180";"180";"180";"180";"180";"180";"180";"180";"180"}**

If there is a formula that forces excel to generate a new number with every row, that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column **A** of your sheet doesn't contain any data you can use the following formula to calculate the sum of 15,000 random numbers between 100 and 200.

Place this formula in cell **B1**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A1:$A15000="")*RANDBETWEEN(100,200))
```

If you are using column **A**, I would suggest hiding it as all rows need to be kept blank in your chosen column. For that reason, I might be tempted to use a column like **ZZ**, or the last available column.

Addition:

Alternatively, this might feel like a better solution in terms of manipulating your variables:

```
SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET($A$1,,,15000)="")*RANDBETWEEN(100,200))
```

Comment: I believe randbetween is only evaluated once so this effectively becomes =randbetween(100,200)*15000.

Comment: Nice try, but I agree with @gtwebb and Nick. I tried both of your variants, and a couple of my own, and, with repeated evaluation (F9), I always got a multiple of 15000. This is infinitesimally unlikely if it is doing what the OP wants. Instead, it must be choosing one random number and adding 15000 copies of it -- in effect, multiplying it by 15000. And "Evaluate Formula" confirms this.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for pointing this out! I was ignoring the most obvious: Mathematically, the more times the RANDBETWEEN(a,b) is calculated, the more the solution should tend to (a + (b-a)/2)*n. I.e. 150*15,000 in the original case. When calculating 15,000 times I would say the difference between using the average of 15,000 random numbers between 100 and 200 and using 150 would be negligible, and would opt for the more simple formula.